# Class that contains a list of objects

Tags: c#, list, foreach, enumerable

I have this class to hold the properties of my data returned from my database call

```
public class Equipment
{
    public string EquipmentId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }

    public Equipment()
    {
        // Default Constructor
    }

    public Equipment(string equipmentId, string description, string model)
    {
        EquipmentId = equipmentId;
        Description = description;
        Model = model;
    }
}
```

Then I have another class that acts as a list of Equipment objects.  My service populates this List without issue but when I try to assign values to my  with a foreach loop I am getting an error: Type <> is not enumerable.

```
public class EquipmentNeedingService : IListSource
{
    public readonly List<Equipment> _equipmentNeedingService = new List<Equipment>();

    public void AddEquipmentToList(Equipment equipment)
    {
        _equipmentNeedingService.Add(equipment);
    }

    System.Collections.IList IListSource.GetList()
    {
        return _equipmentNeedingService;
    }

    public bool ContainsListCollection
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine with this approach through my application but in this specific scenario I am trying to use a foreach loop.  I have read through a few examples but I am not finding exactly what I need and maybe there is a more efficient way to do this?

UPDATE

In the class where I am trying to use this I have a static object that holds the multiple items returned from my database call.

```
private static EquipmentNeedingService _equipmentNeedingService = null;
```

I try to use this in the OnItemDataBound event of my repeater...

```
foreach (var item in _equipmentNeedingService)
{
   // implementation here
}
```

The error I get is from the _equipmentNeedingService in the foreach loop.

Comment: Show the code that gives the error?

Comment: Are you trying to iterate object of `EquipmentNeedingService` or `EquipmentNeedingService._equipmentNeedingService` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I suggest changing your list container class to:

```
public class EquipmentNeedingService : List<Equipment>
{
    // no internal list is need: public readonly List<Equipment> ...();

    // no need to any AddEquipmentToList(), but if you insist:
    public void AddEquipmentToList(Equipment equipment)
    {
        this.Add(equipment);
    }
}
```

Later you can easily enumerate `EquipmentNeedingService` just like any list.

Answer (score 0):

This is your foreach loop:

```
EquipmentNeedingService equipmentNeedingService = new EquipmentNeedingService();
equipmentNeedingService.Add(new Equipment(...));
foreach (Equipment eq in equipmentNeedingService.GetList())
{
}
```

Comment: When I add public I get the error: The modifier 'public' is not valid for explicit interface implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a strong reason for explicit implementation then avoid doing so.    Instead do it implicitly:

```
    public IList GetList()
    {
        return _equipmentNeedingService;
    }
```

Now you can use a foreach:  `foreach (Equipment item in items.GetList())`.

Otherwise, using an explicit implementation complicates things.  [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229034%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> When an interface member is explicitly implemented by a class, the
>   member can be accessed only by using a reference to the interface.

This means that in order to access an explicitly implemented interface then you would have to first cast the object to the type of interface:

`foreach (Equipment item in (items as IListSource).GetList())`